# Use the uniform boundedness principle to show $\sum|y_n|$ converges if $\sum x_ny_n$ converges for every $x\in c_0$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

> Let $y=(y_n),(y_n) \in \mathbb{C}$ be such that $\sum x_n y_n$ converge for every $x=(x_n) \in c_ {0}$ where $c_{0} \subset l^{\infty}$ is the subspace of all complex sequences converging to zero. Show that $\sum|y_n| < \infty$

What I have done is, let $T_n: c_{0} \to \mathbb{C}$ where $T_n(x)=\sum _{i=1}^n x _i y_i$. Then $T_n$
 is linear and bounded, in fact $\|T_n\|= \sum_{i=1} ^n|y_i|$

Now I want to apply uniform boundedness principle to get the result. But for that I have to show that for a fixed $x\in c_{0}$ ,$|T_n(x)|$ is bounded as $n \to \infty$.

Now $|T_n(x)|=| \sum _{i=1}^n x _i y_i| \leq \sum _{i=1}^n| x _i|| y_i|$

From this how can I show $|T_n(x)|$ is  bounded?

Comment: Because $T_n(x)$ converges as $n\rightarrow\infty$, then $\sup_n|T_n(x)| < \infty$. And this is true of every fixed $x$.

Comment: (Principle, not principal.)